# Printing statement in for loop once at the end?

Tags: java

I have a for loop with an if statement inside and I want the statement to print after all the iterations have occurred but it prints after each iteration for which the if statement applies. I want the program to go through the iterations and whatever names start with the letter inputted, I want them to print with the statement "The last names that start with " + letter + " are " + students[i]" only once at the end. Is there a way to do that?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClassNames {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   int numberOfStudents;
   int i;

   System.out.print("Please enter the total number of students: ");
   numberOfStudents = Integer.valueOf(keyboard.next());

   String students[] = new String[numberOfStudents];

   i = 0;
   while(i < numberOfStudents) {
      System.out.print("Enter the last name: ");
      students[i] = keyboard.next();
      i++;
   }   

   String findName;
   System.out.print("Enter a name to search for: ");
   findName = keyboard.next();


   for(i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {

      if(students[i].contains(findName)) {
      System.out.println(findName + " is at index " + i);
      }
       else {
      System.out.println("That name does not exist ");
      break;
      }
   } 

   String letter;

   System.out.print("Enter a letter to search on: ");
   letter = keyboard.next();

   for(i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {

      if(students[i].startsWith(letter)) {
         System.out.println("The last names that start with " + letter + " are " + students[i]);

      }
   }

   }
}
```

Comment: The description of what you *want* the output to be, when comparing to the output I get when I run your code, is not clear. This sample run http://dpaste.com/36S67PN seems to give *almost* the expected output. What do you mean print only once at the end, if there are multiple names that match on the first letter, shouldn't it print, as it does, more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following is what you want:

```
System.out.print("The last names that start with " + letter + " are ");
for (i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
   if (students[i].startsWith(letter)) {
      System.out.print(students[i] + ", ");
   }
}
System.out.println();
```

This will leave with you a trailing comma, but might get you on the road to where you want to be.

Comment: What if there are none?

Comment: Then no names will be printed after the initial text. (And there'll be no trailing comma.)

Comment: Yes, but you'll have a dangling "and the winners are..." sentence, which will look weird. The better way is to say "there were no matching students" if there are no matches, and the sentence if there are some. Your code is a scrape pass or could even be a fail for the tutorial, depending on the standards of the institution.

Comment: If it wasn't clear from the final sentence in my answer, this is not a "production" quality solution. It is a guide to resolving the OP's issue. It's up to them to fine-tune it to meet any specific requirements such as those around no matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can just print `"The last names that start with " + letter + " are "` before the `for` loop and use the loop to print the `student` names.

```
System.out.println("The last names that start with " + letter + " are ");
for(i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
      if(students[i].startsWith(letter)) {
         System.out.print(students[i] + ","); // Comma to separate student names
      }
   }
```

Hope this helps and what you were looking for.

Comment: It is important to note that this uses String concatenation in a loop which should be avoided. Use a StringBuilder instead. The compiler substitutes a StringBuilder for occurrences outside of a loop, but doesn't help us when it occurs inside of a loop.

Comment: Agreed that string concatenation shouldn't be used within a loop. Didn't know compiler substitutes a StringBuilder for occurrences outside a loop. Good thing to know.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out the output before you know the result.

Get the result, and then generate the output. We need to store which names were a match, and display them with one print out. An ArrayList works nicely for this, since we don't know how many names are a match until we are finished looping, which works better than creating an array with a set size that could be too large or too small.

```
List<String> matchesFound = new ArrayList<>();
for (i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
    if (students[i].startsWith(letter)) {
        matchesFound.add(students[i]);
    }
}

if (!matchesFound.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.printf("The last name(s) that starts with %s %s %s.", letter,
         matchesFound.size() > 1 ? "are" : "is", String.join(", ", matchesFound));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer your question as much as I understand your question,
You have two kinds of search: with name and with the first letter.

First of all, if you want to perform a string equality check, better to use .equals or .equals vs .equalsIgnoreCase such that

`if(students[i].equals(findName))`

I will focus on your question and answer for just letter search part. (as search name part is also problematic as it will print else section for each iteration as long as it can not find the name)

So, if you want to print all name starting with letter 'x' (let's assume letter is x) then first, you need to iterate all your names first and save whenever you find a match. You can save those name by using different collections. You can use ArrayList for this specific purpose.

```
  String letter;
   ArrayList<String> matches = new ArraList<String>();
   System.out.print("Enter a letter to search on: ");
   letter = keyboard.next();

   for(i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {

      if(students[i].startsWith(letter)) {
         matches.add(students[i]);

      }
   }
String names = "";
if(!matches.isEmpty)
{
  for(String name : matches)
  { 
    names += name + " "; 
 }
 System.out.println("The last names that start with " + letter + " are " + 
    names);
}
```